# where to put log4j.properties in griffon?

Tags: log4j, griffon, smslib

using smslib in griffon.
and some lib jar(SMSLIB) need log4j.properties.

i had try:
/log4j.properties , /conf/log4j.properties , /lib/log4j.properties

but still error:

> log4j:ERROR Could not read
>   configuration file [log4j.properties].
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:log4j.properties
>   ...
>   log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [log4j.properties].

it seems that the log4j.properties is not copy to classes.

cant find it at staging\classes\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved.

put into griffon-app\resources\

then

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(getClass().classLoader.getResource("log4j.properties"))
```